# Как reduce работает в данном контексте?

Tags: javascript

я думал reduce работает как-то так .reduce((a,b)=>a(b)

А здесь он возвращает сначала функцию ,а затем работает как обычный метод reduce .reduce((a,b)=>(C)=>a(b(c))))

Объясните на пальцах как это работает ?

```js
let b = (str) => {
  let st = str[0]
  return st.toUpperCase()
}

let a = (str) => {
  console.log("im in a")
  return str + "!"
}

const compose = (...funcs) => {
  return funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => (a(b(args))))
}

const comp = compose(a, b)("hey")
console.log(comp)
```

Comment: чем запись в первом абзаце отличается от записи во втором?

Comment: В первом абзаце reduce работает как обычно, а во втором сначала он возвращает функцию ,которая вообще к нему не относится и которую я сам должен вызвать compose(a,b)(“hello”)

Comment: во втором, он также работает как обычно. Просто возвращает не значение, а функцию.

Comment: суть `reduce` как раз в том, что результат возвращенный из callback доступен в качестве первого параметра на следующей итерации.

Comment: Ааа,кажется я понял , reduce возвращает функцию и потом ,когда я ее вызываю (‘hello’)с помощью замыкания выполняется остальная часть reduce a(b(args)))… Верно?

Comment: нет _остальной_ части. тебе reduce возвращает много функций вложенных одна в другую

Comment: А в виде кода можете показать , чтобы наглядно было

Comment: в конце у тебя получается функция типа такой: `()=> a(b(c(d(e(f(...))))))`

Comment: Хм…просто если вызвать compose так : compose(a,b) то в консоль выведется (…args)=>a(b(args))) , я в конец запутался видимо эти сеньорские фокусы не для такого джунчика как я

Comment: в консоль выводится результат работы. В данном случае это функция. Пока не вижу противоречий и чего-то неожиданного